# get JSONS from a single string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i get a single String value as

```
"{"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"LONDON"}, {"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"United Kingdom"}"
```

which contains two jsons  . how can i get each json and put in into an array or something in javascript/jquery ?

Please suggest the best way.

Comment: "two jsons" <- priceless !

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: `JSON.parse('[' + two_jsons + ']')`. Better: Fix the code that generates that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String that you posted isn't valid JSON format. If it is an array of two objects, it should read:

```
'[{"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"LONDON"}, {"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"United Kingdom"}]'
```

Note the single quotes at the beginning and end, so that Javascript doesn't confuse the double quotes in the JSON and can parse them correctly.

Also note the brackets `[]` around the whole thing, that tells the parser that it is an array of objects.

You can read the new string into an object array like this:

```
var str = '[{"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"LONDON"}, {"Link":"","DefaultValue":"","Content":"United Kingdom"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```